# Using gource on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, display

[gource](https://code.google.com/p/gource/) is a software version control visualization tool that I would like to use with Git.  I've installed it on my Raspberry Pi (`sudo apt-get install gource`), but unfortunately when I run it I get this error message:

```
$ gource
gource: SDL initialization failed - couldn't find matching GLX visual
Try 'gource --help' for more information
```

Some commands I ran:

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: :1.0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: Have you tried turning off multi-sampling?

Comment: @Jacobm001 It's off by default, you have to enable it with `--multi-sampling`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research done by myself (with a little help from @Jacobm001), I found that this command solved my issues:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11
```

Now I can view a *very* slow video of my work in Git.  Turning down the resolution helps with the speed.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you get it to work on Raspberry Pi? Doesn't this run on OpenGL which Rapsberry Pi doesn't support?

Comment: @aug I ran these two commands (the one in my question and the one in this answer), and it worked, albeit very slowly.